# Как поставить условие в ограничения в sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть таблица `table_name` и мне в ней нужно поставить ограничение на уникальность по двум полям.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT AK_table_name UNIQUE (field1, field2)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы ограничения срабатывало только если `field1` не является `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX AK_table_name ON table_name
  (CASE WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL
         AND field2 IS NOT NULL
        THEN field1 || ',' || field2
   END);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то что мне нужно было